# email templates and change sets

Tags: email-template, change-set

If I'm moving email templates from one environment to another, do i need to include profiles?  The fields within the environments should be the same, its just the email templates that differ.

Any considerations you recomend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No profiles needed.

Emails, reports, and similar things that are in folders rely on the folder's permission system and don't seem to interact at all with profiles.